# Where can I find Android Studio tutorials on making a simple Notepad and Alarm clock app?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-studio

I am making a small project to combine two of the apps for class, but all I can find online for tutorials are too confusing or long. I'm only gonna use the code, but I am only entry level in java and I don't understand how to use XML and java together. I just haven't learned more code than I should so I looked up tutorials, but like I said, they're not good tutorials for simple projects. Any help is appreciated. If I need to explain myself better, please tell me.

I am trying to understand how to use `SQLite` for the app, and I forgot to mention I can think of an idea on how to use the code for certain projects.

Links:

1. http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html
2. http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-notepad-for-android-devices/27015
3. http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/

Comment: You should add examples of code that you have tried, links to tutorials you found confusing, and ask specific questions (very specific) about things you aren't sure about.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am trying to be specific enough, but thank you for being patient on it. here's the links to the tutorials I tried,  1:https://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html 2:http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-notepad-for-android-devices/27015 3:http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, thank you for the information. i will take care of it in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below instructions to find Google sample code:

1. Click on **File** > **New** > **Import Sample**
2. You will see below window from where you can select any official sample code from Google:

[image]